# 'be + to- infinitive'

Tags: infinitives

*We use 'be+ to- infinitive' when discussing formal or official arrangements or to give formal instructions or orders.It is also used frequently in newspapers, radio and television reports to refer to future events. It expresses near certainty that what is forecast will happen.
Ex-
A man is to appear in court later this morning charged with the murder of the footballer, Darren Gough.*

I found this explanation in BBC Learning English.

I have a doubt that infinitive verbs have any hidden future sense. Like the event of infinitive verb will happen after the main verb or linking verb.
Ex- I am to go. The event of 'to go' will happen in future.

And, even in the case of 'Infinitives of Purpose' it holds the same future sense.

Ex- He is going there to meet his friends.
The event of 'to meet' has not happen yet it would start after reaching there which is also the purpose of his going.

I searched the meaning of  'to be' in a dictionary (Cambridge Dictionary) and in one of its many meanings it gives the idea of something will happen in future.

Ex- We are to(=we are going to) visit Australia in the Spring. ( I haven't done any changes in the example it is written as it was there)

And, in Mediam Webster the definition of 'to be'  is 'that is to be: Future).
Ex- A bride-to-be

So, my question is    do all simple Infinitives  have any future sense hidden in them?

Comment: Do you have a question you would like answered?

Comment: In your example, the quasi-modal verb "be" involves a present schedule to denote a future situation.

Comment: @gotube Yes, sorry for not highlighting the point which I wanted to ask. But now I have added it in my question.

Comment: @BillJ  I have added few more things in the question to clear it more. Can u please address it again

Answer (score 0):

It's very common for `"to" + <base form>` to have a future meaning, but not always:

> She's pretending to be happy.

In that sentence, the pretending and being happy are happening at the same time, so there's no future meaning.

The title of this question and the BBC quote, however, are about `<be> + "to" + <base form>` in particular. This structure always has a future meaning.